# Why the SIGSEGV?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Why is this code throwing up a [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV):

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long toshuffle[9765625];

    unsigned long i;

    for (i=0; i< 1000; i++)
        toshuffle[i]= i;

    return 0;
}
```

Pointers will be appreciated. (No Pun intended :))

Comment: Please, for the love of whatever gods you worship, use "int main(void)" or "int main (int c,char *v[])" The standard has been aroung for ages :-)

Comment: My bad. I do follow that in almost call cases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use malloc() to get that much memory. You're overflowing the stack.

```
unsigned long *toshuffle = malloc(9765625 * sizeof(unsigned long));
```

Of course when you're done with it, you'll need to free() it.

NOTE: In C++, you need to cast the pointer to the correct type.

Comment: "Overflowing the stack", it finally has been said! :)))

Comment: in C++ you would be doing new long[9765625], and wouldn't bother with neither casts nor sizeof... :)

Comment: how to make the compiler to report an error when the stack size is exceeded.

Comment: Thanks Jurily, I should have thought about Stack size and Heap size. But, now I know.

Comment: @iamrohitbanga: At compile time, which is where the compiler works, you do not have an idea about the Stack size that is available to you.

Comment: @Amit is right but it's worse than that. The compiler has *no* idea how big the stack is, it just generates the instructions. The linker *does* know the stack size but has no idea how your code will use it. That means you have to fail at runtime.

Answer (score 9):

Probably because you can't allocate 9765625 longs on stack (what is this site called again? :)). Use `malloc()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)

- RLIMIT_STACK

The maximum size of the process stack, in bytes. Upon reaching this limit, a SIGSEGV signal is generated. To handle this signal, a process must employ an alternate signal stack ([sigaltstack](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaltstack)(2)).